# Card onclick component not getting rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a card. Upon clicking of which I want to render to a new component.
I have written below code for it -

```
function RenderToDetails() {       
  return (<ItemDetails></ItemDetails>);
}

const renderCardInfo = (card,index) => {
  return(
    <Card tag="a" key={index} style={{display:'flex', width:'25%', flexWrap:'nowrap', float:'left', cursor: "pointer"}} onClick={RenderToDetails}>
      <CardBody>
        <CardTitle> {card.value} </CardTitle>
      </CardBody>
    </Card>      
  );
};
```

I can see the `RenderToDetails` function getting called, but cannot see component getting rendered or any error thrown at console either.

How can I render to `ItemDetails` upon clicking of card?

**EDIT 1 : FULL CODE OF Dashboard.js**

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { Card,CardBody, CardTitle } from 'reactstrap';
import ItemDetails from './ItemDetails';


function Dashboard() {
  const initialState = {
      data: [],
      renderToDetails: false
  };

  const [state, setstate] = useState(initialState);
  useEffect(() => {
    const data=[];
      const getData=async () => {
        await axios.get('https://localhost:44301/api/Login/GetItems')
        .then(function (res) {                 
            for (let key in res.data) { 
              data.push({...res.data[key],id:key}); 
            }
            setstate({ data:data });
        });
      }
      getData();
  }, []);

    function RenderToDetails() {       
      return (
        <ItemDetails></ItemDetails>
      );
    }

    const renderCardInfo = (card,index) => {
      return (
        <Card tag="a" key={index} style={{display:'flex',width:'25%',flexWrap:'nowrap',float:'left',cursor: "pointer"}} onClick={RenderToDetails}  >
          <CardBody>
              <CardTitle> {card.value} </CardTitle>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      );
    };

    return (
      <>
        { state.data.map(renderCardInfo) }
      </>
    );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: I don't think you can put return() inside the renderCardInfo

Comment: @AKMIntisarIslam what coul be the solution ?

Comment: Can you pls share the component's full code?

Comment: @AKMIntisarIslam sir please check EDIT1

Comment: I tried but couldn't solve it. The code seems messy to me. I would recommend you to follow the reactjs documentation and organize the code. It may solve your problem fast.
Sorry for not being able to help you out.

Comment: @AKMIntisarIslam - No  issues brother. Thanks you tried :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoking the **RenderToDetails** function in the onClick event wouldn't render the  component in the Dashboard. Basically, you never told react when and where to render your component.

So you need to add the  component to the render function and toggle the showInfo state to hide/unhide the component.

Use the below code -

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { Card,CardBody, CardTitle } from 'reactstrap';
import ItemDetails from './ItemDetails';


function Dashboard() {
  const initialState = {
      data: [],
      renderToDetails: false,
      showInfo: false
  };

  const [state, setstate] = useState(initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    const data=[];
      const getData=async () => {
        await axios.get('https://localhost:44301/api/Login/GetItems')
        .then(function (res) {                 
            for (let key in res.data) { 
              data.push({...res.data[key],id:key}); 
            }
            setstate({ data:data });
        });
      }
      getData();
  }, []);

    function RenderToDetails() {       
      return (
        <ItemDetails></ItemDetails>
      );
    }

    const renderCardInfo = (card,index) => {
      return (
        <Card tag="a" key={index} style={{display:'flex',width:'25%',flexWrap:'nowrap',float:'left',cursor: "pointer"}} onClick={() => setstate({...state, showInfo: !state.showInfo})}  >
          <CardBody>
              <CardTitle> {card.value} </CardTitle>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      );
    };

    return (
      <>
        { state.data.map((card, index) => renderCardInfo(card, index)) }
        { state.showInfo && RenderToDetails()}
      </>
    );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: While I agree that this is the correct approach, code-only answers are generally not ideal. Adding a bit of explanation about what you have done (and why) will change this from a snippet that the asker can copy-paste, to something they can easily learn from.

Comment: @DBS Dhilip - component is getting rendered 4 times , as I have 4 items in card -  { state.data.map(renderCardInfo) }

Comment: So, your requirement is to have a single <ItemDetails/> component in the dashboard, and you want to toggle it on/off when any of the 4 cards is clicked?

Comment: @DBS Thanks! I'll update the answer with an explanation

Comment: @DhilipH yes , i dont want to render it 4 times